# Extraction of URI,abstract and subject from DBPEDIA?

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

I want to extract URI, abstract and subject through SPARQL query on dbpedia in which the URI matches the name of our song (regardless of uppercase and lowercase) and the abstract **OR** our subject contains one of our artist names as I have marked in this jpeg. Please provide the SPARQL for this query?

[image]

[image]

Comment: SPARQL is too confusing to attempt, I am somewhat conversant with programming. But I cannot hang of this SPARQL stuff.

Comment: RDF and SPARQL are far away from being confusing - at least not the simplest things. Any RDF and SPARQL tutorial can help. `SELECT * WHERE {?s ?p ?o . }`

Comment: use Wikidata query instead DPedia: https://query.wikidata.org/

Answer (score 0):

On http://dbpedia.org/sparql/, Try this:

```
select DISTINCT ?song
where {

?song a dbo:MusicalWork.
?song dbo:abstract ?abstractText.
?song dct:subject ?subjectText.
FILTER(regex(str(?abstractText),"The platters","i") || regex(str(?subjectText),"The platters","i") ).

}
```

Or if you want to use the musical artist of the song, you could try:

```
select DISTINCT ?song
where {

?song a dbo:MusicalWork.
?song dbo:musicalArtist dbr:The_Platters.

}
```